# Building a Deque using arrays in java (using generics)

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a Deque using java arrays. Due to the requirements, I need to use generics so I have the following code:

```
public class Deque<Item>{
   private Item[] deque;
   
   public Deque(){
      deque= new Item[10];
}
```

I am aware this is wrong but this is how I think an array should be initialized. It would be great if someone could give me the right way to go about doing this.

Comment: I have to use the private field Item[] given in the code since it is required otherwise I might have used another data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is internal to the class, you can do something like this.

```
    public Deque() {
        deque = (Item[]) new Object[10];
    }
```

You need to do this as generics undergo type erasure at runtime. Since java arrays are covariant, you can substitute with any subclass of `Object`.